# Command timeout SQL Server 2014 + Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have installed SQL Server 2014 on my new PC yesterday, it was working until I restarted my PC, now I am getting this error.

I have started / restarted SQL Server services etc..

I can still connect from Management Studio.

When adding EF model to my asp.net project, it can list databases and get tables to generate EF model, but I can't do anything with the database because of this timeout exception, database is almost empty (only 1 table with 1 user in) and I am executing simple queries (like select, add)

```
using(var db = new TestEntities())
{
    var _user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(); // timeout exception
}
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>          at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

Comment: OK I have found solution, I need to write "db.Database.Connection.Open();" to make it work, why doesn't it opens connection automatically?

Comment: lol wut? you don't have to do that especially if used using. there is something else wrong here pal

Answer (score 0):

Set the timeout on the command

[SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

There is probably another problem

And test a simple select like select @@versino

Comment: var x = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT @@VERSION"); // got -1 returned

Comment: Well you got something so keep digging

Comment: well, i'm going to fully reinstall sql server

Comment: I would create a new db on the server before a full reinstall.  If you have not installed service packs that might fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Press window + r  >  "services.msc" > SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) > Right Click > Start

The sql server instance is closed therefore server couldn't respond.

Comment: It is already started, I can connect from Management Studio and do anything with the database, EF can also generate model and connect, the thing is that I only can't execute any query, getting timeout

Comment: 30188 milliseconds

Comment: OK I have found solution, I need to write "db.Database.Connection.Open();" to make it work, why doesn't it opens connection automatically?

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that the TCP/IP protocol is not enabled? Check SQL Server Configuration Manager.
It could also be that it's not accepting remote connections. For that, you need to check with SQL Server Management Studio, server properties, Connections.

Comment: The comment above says it works if the connection is opened manually.